# How to use JavaScript and offsetWidth to line up tables?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've inherited this project that goes about things in an old-fashioned way.  For instance, it uses tables for layout, which is bad enough, but then it breaks apart headers and content into two separate tables (see my code snippet).

It's not really practical to go about re-writing the markup, so the solution will have to be a JavaScript one, combined with CSS probably.  Keep in mind that I've vastly simplified the issue for the purposes here to make things less confusing; in reality, the problem stretches over many different files.

Using JavaScript (see the snippet), I'm able to *mostly* line up the headers with the body.  The idea is to wait until the page loads, find the widths of the body elements, and then apply them to the headers to make it look like one table.  As you can see, it doesn't exactly match up.  This is in part because of the CSS borders, but life is messy and borders happen.  It's not realistic to remove all additional CSS just to make things line up.

Can you help me get these tables to line up and look like one table?

Edit:

To be a bit clearer on the requirements, the table needs to be sized dynamically, based on the widths of the content in the body table.  The content might change, so it won't be sufficient to hard-code widths.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var bodyCols = document.getElementsByClassName('bodyCol');
  var headCols = document.getElementsByClassName('headCol');

  for (var i=0; i<bodyCols.length; i++) {
    headCols[i].style.minWidth = bodyCols[i].offsetWidth + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
#headTable {
  width: 100%;
}

.headCol { 
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#bodyTable {
  width: 100%;
}

.bodyCol { 
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table id="headTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="headCol">
        Hey!
      </td>
      <td class="headCol">
        Wait!
      </td>
      <td class="headCol">
        I've got a new complaint
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="bodyTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="bodyCol">
        Forever in debt
      </td>
      <td class="bodyCol">
        to your priceless
      </td>
      <td class="bodyCol">
        advice
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should probably look into refactoring that code. Maintaining it and adding to it will only increase your technical debt and make your project harder and harder to work with.

Comment: It's a consideration but I'm hopeful I can make superficial changes to get it running again.  It was written over 10 years ago for whatever Internet Explorer was running then.  Any significant change to the markup ends up breaking a bunch of other things, and I don't want to go down that road.

Comment: If it's something that you're just supposed to "make it work" then fair enough. But if you're expected to continue development on it then refactoring is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a solution using pure JavaScript.

```
var bodyCols = document.querySelectorAll('.bodyCol');
var headCols = document.querySelectorAll('.headCol');

for(var i = 0; i < bodyCols.length; i++){
    console.log(headCols[i]);
  headCols[i].style.width = window.getComputedStyle(bodyCols[i]).width;
}
```

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/pbjzmanc/

Comment: My only push-back against this solution is the requirement (admittedly I could have made it clearer in the question) that the columns are sized by the body content.  I'm not completely sure how yours works, but your widest column also has the shortest body content.  Is there a way to adapt your solution so that the column widths are proportional to the body content (ie the original size of the table before headers are added)?

Comment: Try adding `.headCol:last-of-type{width: 20%;}` to the CSS. Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/k5h1hmqx/1/

Comment: I think that's sidestepping the issue a bit.  The content might change and I don't want to update the CSS every time it does.  I'll update the question to be clearer.

Comment: Wasn't too familiar with "getComputedStyle" but it seems to be the precise answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time on this and came up with a jQuery solution.  Now, I didn't mention jQuery in the question and ideally I wouldn't have to include it in my project just for this one problem.  However, it does solve the problem nicely and I don't know of a way to do it otherwise.  I will leave off marking this as the correct answer for now in the hopes someone can show me how to do this with plain JavaScript.

```js
$(function() {  
  $('.bodyCol').each(function(index) {
    $('.headCol:eq(' + index + ')').innerWidth($(this).innerWidth());
  });
});
```

```css
#headTable {
  width: 100%;
}

.headCol { 
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#bodyTable {
  width: 100%;
}

.bodyCol { 
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="headTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="headCol">
        Hey!
      </td>
      <td class="headCol">
        Wait!
      </td>
      <td class="headCol">
        I've got a new complaint
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="bodyTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="bodyCol">
        Forever in debt
      </td>
      <td class="bodyCol">
        to your priceless
      </td>
      <td class="bodyCol">
        advice
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Updated my answer with a javascript-only solution :)